# android searchview not responding setQuery and other commands

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to add a Hint on androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView but my searchView is not responding to any command even after using setQueryHint,i tried using other commands like searchView.setIconified(false) and searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false) and my searchView still doesn't respond to any of the  commands, my searchView is implemented within the toolbar from a menu.xml file and not directly from the fragments.xml file so i cannot set my hint from the fragments.xml file but from the fragments java file and my searchView is showing just fine but  without any change implemented by the code.

here is the menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
</menu>
```

here is the fragment.java file:

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    SearchManager searchManager=(SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.setQueryHint("Xavier search for stuff");
    searchView.setIconified(false);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);


    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}
```

here is the fragments.xml file:

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"
    >  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_ios_24"
    android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_5sdp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Discover"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_6sdp"/>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```